# More efficient way to count single int from array?

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to squeeze every but out of my Java Othello program and have a point where I need to count the number of instances a given number appears. For instance array[]{1,1,2,1,0,1} would count(1) returns 4. Below was an attempt I made at speed by counting all numbers but this was slower:

```
public void count(int color) { 
    byte count[] = new byte[3];

    for (byte i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        ++count[state[i]];

    return count[color];
}
```

So far this is the most efficient code I have tested:

```
public void count(int color) {  
    byte count = 0;

    for (byte i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
        if (this.get(i) == color)
            count++;

    return count;
}
```

Does anyone think they could squeeze some more speed out of this? I only need the count of the number specified, nothing more.

Comment: You can really only make this faster if the arrays is sorted, smaller, or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `int`, not `byte` - internally, Java converts the byte to an int, then increments it, then converts it back to a byte; using an int obviates the need for the type conversions.

You can also try using an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), its `getAndIncrement` method may be faster than the `++` operator.

You can also unroll your loop; this will reduce the number of times that `i < 64` is evaluated.  Try using an AtomicInteger for `i`, and use `getAndIncrement` instead of `++`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 64;) {
    if(this.get(i++) == color) ...
    if(this.get(i++) == color) ...
    if(this.get(i++) == color) ...
    if(this.get(i++) == color) ...
}
```

Changing the for loop to a do-while loop may be slightly faster - the for loop has a conditional jump and an unconditional jump, but a do-while loop only has a conditional jump.

You can do this in parallel (thread1 counts elements 0-15, thread2 counts elements 16-31, etc), but the cost of creating the threads probably isn't worth it.

Answer (score 2):

try making count `int` instead of `byte` some architectures have trouble handling single `bytes` so a byte is smaller in memory but problematic to make calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections for this purpose. But your array should be type of Integer because collection don't support primitive types.

```
public void count(int color) {  
   List<Integer> asList = Arrays.asList(your_Array);  
   return  Collections.frequency(asList,color);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) this.get(i) in version 2 seems suspicious, if we are dealing with array, array[i] is supposed to be more efficient.

2) I would replace

```
byte count = 0;
for (byte i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
...
```

with

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
...
```

otherwise Java will need to promote byte operands to int to do arithmetic and then truncate results to byte.

3) Use http://code.google.com/p/caliper/ to get good benchmarks